# Saving all values in "multiple select"

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

im having a metabox in wordpress with a mutliple select form.

```
<select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select" multiple="" style="width:300px; height:400px;">
    <option value="red">Red
    </option>
    <option value="blue">Blue
    </option>
</select>
```

So far so good, the selected value gets saved and I am able to retrieve it, however I wish for both values to be saved.

For example I wish to save both red AND blue and be able to retrieve it from the frontend. Is there any way to achieve this? Are there better forms than a select?

The purpose is for a user to select pages from one select field to another and then save the second select field.

select 1:

red

blue

green

Select 2:

orange

-button-

Now if a user where to select `red` and `blue` from `select 1` and then press `-button-` the values will be added to select 2. When I now press update page I wish to save all the values in select 2.

This is how i save from my current select field (but it only saves ONE selected value)

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
```

Comment: With multiple select fields, make sure you make them an array. `name="my_meta_box_select[]"` will make your `$_POST['my_meta_box_select']` actually contain all values as an array. Then you can loop through.

Comment: Well that is just fantastic news! Thank you so much!

Comment: Going to post an official answer so it's all more legit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often overlooked, super simple.

The name attribute needs to allow for multiple selections to be sent over `$_POST` as an array. For example:

```
<select name="my_meta_box_select[]" id="my_meta_box_select" multiple="" style="width:300px; height:400px;">
    <option value="red">Red
    </option>
    <option value="blue">Blue
    </option>
</select>
```

Notice the `[]` in the name:  `name="my_meta_box_select[]"`

This, alongside the `multiple` attribute, will allow your `$_POST` variable to contain all selections as an array. That said, `$_POST['my_meta_box_select']` will not just be a simple value, but rather will be an array will all selections.

Comment: It seems to save it as an array, but when i do this:
    $testVar = get_post_meta( $GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'my_meta_box_select', true );

    print_r ($testVar);

It only prints out 'Array'

Same if I run a foreach trough it. It seem to save it as an array but I can t get the elements of it somehow

Am I grabbing it wrong with
    $testVar = get_post_meta( $GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'my_meta_box_select', true );

Comment: var_dump($testVar); gives me string(5) "Array"

Comment: So what it seem to do is only saving the word "Array" instead of the values in an array, any idea how to correct this problem? :/

Comment: In my case, it's not even saving the array. My option values are simply numbers. It's just saving the last number of the options set. I have [] at the end of my name attribute and I also have the multiple attribute present as well.

Answer (score 2):

adding [] to the `name` was correct, however I allso needed to replace the following save line:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', esc_attr( $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
```

with the following:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_box_select', array_map( 'strip_tags', $_POST['my_meta_box_select'] ) );
```

Thanks alot for the assistance Nate!

Comment: Woo! Glad you got it working! Hope everything is great now :)